# when we can see the latest version of IBM websphere commerce WCS9

Tags: e-commerce, websphere-commerce, wcs

IBM eCommerce, WebSphere Commerce Suite 8 is the current available version. When will IBM release their latest version of IBM WCS9?

Comment: Have a look at this link http://www-01.ibm.com/common/ssi/ShowDoc.wss?docURL=/common/ssi/rep_ca/4/897/ENUS217-284/index.html

Comment: Thanks for the info @RanjithV . Can see IBM WCE V9 details in ibm portals  is it same to WCS9, I mean just another term used to represent the new features in WCS9.